# Subview not moving along with its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, subview, superview

I've done this a million times before but finding myself confused now.
When you animate a container view to change its position, its subviews move along with it don't they? You don't change subviews' frames you just change superview's frame because all subviews' positions inside their superview don't change.

But for some reason this time the subviews would not move along with their superview, it'd stay stuck at its original position.

```
- (void)writeCommentTapped{

    UIView *writeCommentView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    writeCommentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview: writeCommentView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.navView];

    self.writeCommentTextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    self.writeCommentTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [writeCommentView addSubview:self.writeCommentTextView];
    [self.writeCommentTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    self.writeCommentTextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;

    writeCommentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.keyboardSize.height);
    self.writeCommentTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, writeCommentView.frame.size.width - 40, writeCommentView.frame.size.height - 100);
    self.writeCommentTextView.center = writeCommentView.center;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         writeCommentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, writeCommentView.frame.size.width, writeCommentView.frame.size.height);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {

                         }
                     }
     ];

}
```

Comment: is autolayout enabled for your viewcontroller in the storyboard?

Comment: All done programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove self.writeCommentTextView.center and set calculated frame for center

```
-(void)writeCommentTapped{


    UIView *writeCommentView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    writeCommentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview: writeCommentView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.navView];

    self.writeCommentTextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    self.writeCommentTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [writeCommentView addSubview:self.writeCommentTextView];
    [self.writeCommentTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    self.writeCommentTextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;

    writeCommentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.keyboardSize.height);
    writeCommentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


    self.writeCommentTextView.frame = CGRectMake(40/2, 100/2, writeCommentView.frame.size.width - 40, writeCommentView.frame.size.height - 100);
//    self.writeCommentTextView.center = writeCommentView.center;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         writeCommentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, writeCommentView.frame.size.width, writeCommentView.frame.size.height);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {

                         }
                     }
     ];
}
```

OR

```
self.writeCommentTextView.center = CGPointMake(writeCommentView.frame.size.width/2.0, writeCommentView.frame.size.height/2.0);
```

Comment: I knew removing self.writeCommentTextView.center would do it but why doesn't it work with .center?

Comment: it would not work because you are setting self.writeCommentTextView.center = writeCommentView.center which is not correct center because writeCommentView.center is the center of writeCommentView on its parentView which is outside of the screen.

Comment: if you really want to set center, do this self.writeCommentTextView.center = CGPointMake(writeCommentView.frame.size.width/2.0, writeCommentView.frame.size.height/2.0);

Comment: Fantastic. Did not know that.